# Change html inside span onClick within slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I'm looking to show the contents of a ul when a heading is clicked but also change the icon next to that heading. As default the icon is a down arrow, when clicked the ul should slide open and the icon should change to an up arrow, and when clicked again it should change to a down arrow etc etc.

I can get this to happen once but once the heading is clicked twice just stays as an up arrow, I'd like to change this again to a down arrow etc etc. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

My HTML code:

```
<h4 class="mobileDrop">Find Your Way Around <span><i class="fa fa-caret-down linkIcon"></i></span></h4>

<ul class="footerNav">
     <li><a href="#">1st List Item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">2nd List Item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">3rd List Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

My code JS:

```
// footer specifics
$( ".footerNav" ).hide();
// toggle on click
$( ".mobileDrop" ).click(function() {
    $( ".footerNav" ).slideToggle( 400, function()  {
        $( ".mobileDrop span" ).html( '<i class="fa fa-caret-up linkIcon"></i>' );  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change html. Simply toggle class.

```
$( ".mobileDrop" ).click(function() {
    var drop = $(this);
    $( ".footerNav" ).slideToggle( 400, function()  {
        drop.find('.fa.linkIcon').toggleClass('fa-caret-up fa-caret-down');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/qY7as/3/

```
 $( ".footerNav" ).hide();
// toggle on click
$( ".mobileDrop" ).click(function() {
    $( ".footerNav" ).slideToggle( 400, function()  {

        $( ".mobileDrop span" ).html( '<i class="fa fa-caret-up linkIcon"></i>' );  

         var yourElement = $( ".mobileDrop span i").attr('class');
        //check class and give it what you want
        $( ".mobileDrop span i").attr('class','new value with class and new background icon');
    });
});

<h4 class="mobileDrop">Find Your Way Around 
    <span></span>
</h4>

<ul class="footerNav">
     <li><a href="#">1st List Item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">2nd List Item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">3rd List Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks faby, but this is just the same code as I posted pretty much. I have the dropdown dorking but I need the icon to be a down arrow when the page loads, hence the reason for the icon in the span to start with, then when clicked the icon changes to an up arrow, then when clicked again the icon changes to a down arrow etc etc.

Comment: I have updated the answer.. look that.. sorry for the wrong post

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one `caret-` class by default:

```
// footer specifics
$( ".footerNav" ).hide();
// toggle on click
$( ".mobileDrop" ).click(function() {
$( ".footerNav" ).slideToggle( 400, function()  {
    $( ".mobileDrop span i" ).toggleClass('fa-caret-up').toggleClass('fa-caret-down');  
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( ".footerNav" ).slideToggle( 400, function()  {
    var linkIcon = $(".linkIcon");
    if (linkIcon.hasClass('fa-caret-down')) {
        linkIcon.removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-up');
    } else {
        linkIcon.removeClass('fa-caret-up').addClass('fa-caret-down');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is toggle between the classes:

```
$( ".mobileDrop span i" ).toggleClass('fa-caret-up ','fa-caret-down');
```

They will switch classes automatically according to the clicked intervals.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EUGUK/)**

#### Reference:

[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Answer (score 0):

As for display / not the display the menu you could just use :

```
$( ".mobileDrop" ).click(function() {
    $(".footerNav").toggle();
});
```

as for the arrow, you could use two classes each for different arrow or just change the background-image css each time using `toggleClass`